# Loop Error in Query

Tags: php, mysql

i want to search data from databse
that how many no of bids are placed by users for that i have to first search member id from a table tbl_members than from that member id i am searching the no of bids from a table tbl_bids
then from tbl_bids am also getting  the product_id means on which product id the bids are placed then according to this product id amd getting the product name from tbl_products

here is my code for this process

```
 fkdslfsd
```

fd
sf
ds
fds
f
sd
fdsgfhfgfghfgh
gf
hfg

fgbfd
bfdb
vcb
vcb
vcb
vc
b
cb
f
gfdg
fdg
fdg
fd
gdf
g
fdg
fd
gdf

am getting everything but opnly error am getting is that the product and everything is repeating according to no of bids

please check here
www.snapbid.in/make/dashboard.php

and search for damodar you will and check his details

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are outputting one row for each *bid* rather than each *auction* (which is what I think you want). I can't really post an updated version of your code as your code is a mess. Here are some pointers:

- Please post nicely formatted code so people can help you. No-one wants to plow through code like yours above,
- Please read up on [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection). Never use values from outside your code ($_GET and $_POST etc) directly in queries. If you're expecting an integer at the very least use [intval()](http://uk.php.net/intval),
- The mysql_ functions are considered somewhat deprecated. Better to use mysqli_ or even better PDO and bind your parameters,
- Please read up on [JOINS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html). It is very rarely a good idea to have multiple SQL queries within loops.

For example you could probably rewrite all your queries in your example to something like this.

```
SELECT
    a.auction_id,
    a.auction_startdate,
    a.auction_enddate,
    p.product_name,
    p.product_price,
    COUNT( DISTINCT b.bid_id) as num_bids
FROM
    tbl_auctions a
    INNER JOIN
        tbl_products p ON a.product_id=p.product_id
    INNER JOIN
        tbl_bids b ON a.auction_id=b.auction_id
WHERE
    b.member_id = $member_id
GROUP BY
    a.auction_id
```

Comment: it's not just the code that should be properly formatted. The text itself should at the very least have proper punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @liquorvicar, you should be returning all this data with a single query.  The only thing he was missing was the GROUP BY clause -

```
SELECT
    a.auction_id,
    a.auction_startdate,
    a.auction_enddate,
    p.product_name,
    p.product_price,
    COUNT(b.bid_id) as num_bids
FROM
    tbl_auctions a
INNER JOIN
    tbl_products p ON a.product_id=p.product_id
INNER JOIN
    tbl_bids b ON a.auction_id=b.auction_id
WHERE
    b.member_id = $member_id
GROUP BY
    a.auction_id,
    a.auction_startdate,
    a.auction_enddate,
    p.product_name,
    p.product_price;
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out (although maybe a comment would have been better?). I think you only actually need to group on auction_id. I've edited my answer.

Comment: I felt an answer was justified as your answer, without the GROUP BY clause, was incorrect. [MySQL allows](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html) you to write the GROUP BY on just the auction_id but most RDBMSs will not.